# iOS - Content type error with RestKit

Tags: ios, restkit, content-type

executing a GET request as follows:

```
manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kBaseUrl]];
[manager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"application/json"];
[manager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];

RKObjectRequestOperation* operation = [manager appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodGET path:@"www.mypath.com" parameters:nil];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    ....    
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    ....
}];
[manager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
```

even if the content type is set as 'application/json' I get:

> Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
>       "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
>       "text/html",
>       "application/json"
>   )}, got application/javascript"

Any idea?

Comment: Which content type? The server is returning the wrong content type...

Comment: Hi Wain, I'm talking about the request content type. Proxying the network traffic I see the requests are done with application/javascript indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that no matter what the request content type is, the server's answer has always content type 'application/javascript'.

The solution is:

```
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"application/javascript"];
```